# Count of selected items in a MultiList

Tags: sxa, presentation, nvelocity

I need to view the number of selected items in a MultiList field using out of the box SXA (1.7) components(i.e. no custom coding).

I tried doing this with a rendering variant NVelocity template using `$item.List`. This returned a string with the id's of the items separated by | .

[image]

I also would rather not use javascript. Any out of the box solution like NVelocity or suggestion without custom coding?

Comment: Did you try $item.List.Count() ?  (didn't try myself, but that would be my first guess)

Comment: i did, i also tried size and length. but its a string so it didn't work.

Comment: $item.List.Count(c => c == '|') + 1 ?  Or $item.List.Count(c => c == '{')..

Comment: Thank you for your help , but Is this c# code ? because that didn't work in the rendering variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an OOTB NVelocity function that can handle splits and counts.

So.. one option would be to write an NVelocity function - which is not that hard, but does require custom code and that is not what you wanted.

But I did find a way to do this in NVelocity without a custom function (note that a custom function would make this code cleaner and more reusable):

```
#set ($counter = 0)
#foreach($character in $item.List)
#if ($character.ToString() == "{")
#set ($counter = $counter + 1)
#end
#end
Length: $counter
```

The last line will display your number of items - adapt that one as needed..

Like I mentioned - if you need this at more than one spot: go for a custom function ([example here](https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2017/04/custom-rendering-variant-token-tool-for-sxa.html) by Michael West). Also not sure about the performance of this code.. but it does work.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers as accepted when they are sufficient for you (I've noticed that you haven't done this for your other questions either) ;)